# my Rack::Static middleware works with root url in urls parameter and without

Tags: ruby, rack

I have this in my `config.ru`:

```
require 'rack'
require './app.rb'

use(Rack::Static,
  :urls => %w(/css /fonts /images /js),
  :root => '../static',
  :index => 'index.html')
end

run MyApp
```

it correctly serves static files for all four of the above URLs, but in addition, it also serves `index.html` from the root URL as if I had `:urls => %w(/ /css /fonts /images /js)` and I do not understand why this is happening. I could not find any explanation in the documentation.

Comment: This is possibly a bug in Rack. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/static.rb#L99), if an `index` is provided Rack only checks if the path ends with `/`, and not that the path matches any of the URLs specified. I don’t think that would be intentional.

Comment: @matt thanks. posted an issue: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/740